# System does not boot without entering BIOS

Tags: windows-10, boot, bios

I have a HP Omen Gaming PC (870-155ng) that, without any changes from my side, suddenly can't be booted anymore unless I enter BIOS or otherwise interact when booting up.

The manufacturer (HP Omen Logo) shows up, and when it would normally show the loading spinner for Windows (10, in my case) underneath, it stays at that screen until I interact with it (open BIOS and leave without changing anything, enter and leave bios level diagnostics mode, press delete).

What I tried was and didn't help:

- Update BIOS with HPs latest BIOS firmware
- Check for updates on my hardware (latest drivers should be installed)
- change my BIOS battery since I never changed it
- Disconnected power cable for 5+ minutes to check BIOS battery was still broken somehow
- HP built in BIOS level diagnostics showed not issues
- check my hard drives SMART status, it said no predicted failure state
- Legacy boot mode is disabled, boot order seemed fine.
- I'm not overclocking

Any idea on what I could still troubleshoot to solve this issue?

Comment: Try resetting BIOS to default values, saving and restarting the computer.

Comment: "Reset settings to default" didn't help.
The only option for actually reset BIOS is not working, the system tells me the firmware for the original BIOS cannot be found to be reset to.

Comment: Contact HP Support for assistance.  That seems the only route open now

Answer (score 1):

1. If you have *any* USB devices connected, unplug them.
2. In BIOS, disable network boot and be sure the internal SSD and/or HDD is first in boot order.
3. As a diagnostic, you might try booting from a Live USB, e.g., [WinRE](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/how-to-access-windows-recovery-environment-winre/eaa88d77-5924-41c8-accf-ea7bed0cd8b8) or [Ubuntu](https://ubuntu.com/tutorials/create-a-usb-stick-on-ubuntu#1-overview), to see if it will automatically boot (of course, you'll need to set the boot order, beforehand).

**If the PC boots from USB without intervention**, then very likely the Windows boot partition needs repair.

- Try the [Windows Startup Repair Tool](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/client-management/advanced-troubleshooting-boot-problems).

or

- Make a full disk image, lest data be lost on the next step!
- Download the [Windows 10 ISO](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10ISO) and install it on USB with the Windows Media Creation Tool.
- Perform installation/repair from the USB, *keeping all files and settings.*

There are also third-party tools, such as [Macrium Reflect Free,](https://www.macrium.com/reflectfree) that can repair boot issues.